# How can I transform a notes view to a html nested list?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I would like to re-use a notes view in a web browser, Therefor I need the notes view (with response documents hierarchy) represented in HTML as an unordered list (ul) with list items (li).

What SSJS code should I use to compute this list?

Comment: What have you tried? Remember SO is not the do my work site, but the get unstuck place

Answer (score 0):

None.

If you can edit the view, set it to passthru HTML and add one column at the beginning and end with the list tags. Set them hidden from client.

Or bind it to a repeat control and have the Li tags inside with computed text bound to the view columns. No SsJS in both cases.

Comment: option 1 is undesirably; I would like to use the view data on an xpage. option 2 I do not understand quiet well. nested lists do not follow a real categorized structure, I mean there are response to response threads...

Answer (score 0):

NotesViewEntry.getPosition(Char separator) gives a hierarchical output. For example with the separator defined as "." it will give 3 for the third top-level entry, 3.5 for the fifth child of the third top-level entry, 3.5.7 for the seventh child of the fifth child of the third top-level entry.

To elaborate on Stephan's second option, a Repeat Control doesn't care about the structure of the data it's retrieving. It's a handle to a collection, where each "row" is one element in that collection. So if you point it to a collection which is myView.getAllEntries(), each entry is a NotesViewEntry.

Combine the two and you have the level of the hierarchy, if you want to just use indentation. Alternatively, from a NotesViewEntry you can tell if there are children, so whether you need to make it another li or start another ul.

Alternatively, if you want to get more elaborate, look at how I traverse views to create a Dojo Tree Grid navigation in XPages Help Application http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XPages%20Help%20Application

Answer (score 0):

not the most beautiful code. I hope it works;

```
function getList() {
    var nav:NotesViewNavigator=database.getView("notesview").createViewNav();
    var entry:NotesViewEntry=nav.getFirst();
    if (entry!=null){
        var countLevel:Integer = 0;
        var curLevel:Integer;
        var list="";
        while (entry != null) {
            var edoc:NotesDocument = entry.getDocument();
            entryValue = entry.getColumnValues().elementAt(1).toString();
            var col:NotesDocumentCollection = edoc.getResponses();       
            var gotResponse:String;
            if (col.getCount()>0){
                gotResponse ="1";
            }
            else{
                gotResponse ="0";
            }
            curLevel = entry.getColumnIndentLevel();  

            if (curLevel<countLevel){
                //no responses & no siblings
                var difLevel=countLevel-curLevel;
                list=list + "<li>"+entryValue+ "</li>"

                var closure="";
                for (var i=0;i<(difLevel);i++) {
                    closure=closure+"</ul></li>"
                }
                list=list+closure;
                countLevel=curLevel;
            }

            if (curLevel==countLevel){
                if(gotResponse=="1"){
                    //got responses;handle them first
                    list=list+"<li>";
                    list=list+entryValue;
                    list=list+"<ul>";
                    countLevel=curLevel+1;
                }
                else{
                    //must be sibling
                    list=list + "<li>"+entryValue+ "</li>"
                }               
            }               
            var tmpentry:NotesViewEntry=nav.getNext(entry);
            entry.recycle();
            entry=tmpentry;             
        }
        //final closure, last entry could be response doc
        var closure = ""
        for (var i = 0; i < (countLevel); i++) {
            closure = closure + "</ul></li>";
        }
        list = list + closure;


        return list;
    } else {
        return "No documents found";
    }
}
```